# Sikuli ide special caracters :, \ doesn' t pass through

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am using Sikuli ide,

I want to do a very simple type("1440144711350.png", "C:\tests\exportDest.csv")

But it doesn' t seems to work, when i run it, i got errors, what' s the problem may be coming from ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the errors?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I suppose you are trying to find or open a file from the windows explorer, or something similar.

The `type` function simulates the Standard US keyboard, can be tricky if you do not have one. Have a look to [SikuliX documentation on the function type](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.type). You certainly then have to prefer the method `paste`

The second issue you certainly encounter is linked to the backslash that is interpreted in your string (for example \t is interpreted as tab). you have to escape them with a `\\`
To verify it: simply paste (Ctrl+V) in atext editor after running your script can provide you an idea what sikuli tried to paste...

```
    paste("1440144711350.png", "C:\\tests\\exportDest.csv")
```

if needed you can simply press the enter key afterwards as following:

```
    paste("1440144711350.png", "C:\\tests\\exportDest.csv")
    type(Key.ENTER)
```